# filling an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, fill

Hello there stackoverflow users, im trying to initialize and fill my arrays with numbers and then find the max value of it, but when i start to fill array i get zeros or samenumbers which i input or ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or array stops with fill, i tryed few days but i really dont know what to do now, i have logical mistakes, please help.

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int[] array = initializeArray();
        int max = max(array);
        System.out.println(max);
    }
    public static int[] initializeArray() throws IOException {


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int Numbers[] = new int[5];

        if (in.hasNext())
        {
        for(int NumCntr = 0 ; NumCntr< Numbers.length ;NumCntr++)
        {
            Numbers[NumCntr] = in.nextInt();


        }
            System.out.println(Numbers);

        }

        return Numbers;
    }


    public static int max(int[] array) {


        int maxt = 0;

        for(int i=0;i < 5;i++)
        {
            if(array[i] >  array[i+1])
                maxt = array[i];
        }


        return maxt;




    }
}
```

Comment: Try to describe what each line of your code in max method is doing.

Comment: please have a look at naming conventions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array size is 5 but at below loop for max value of `i` you are incrementing it by 1, and so trying to access `array[5]` (`array[4+1]`), which causes your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
     for(int i=0;i < 5;i++)
            {
                if(array[i] >  array[i+1])
--------------------------------------^
                    maxt = array[i];
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, but how is possible that i get 1
2
3
4
5
[I@2f5e8a8f  <<<<< this
5

Comment: wlc @Predict_it,ur array size is 5 it mean you can access the array index[0-4] but in the loop you was trying to access index[5] for i=4 due to which exception arise

Comment: @Predict_it Take a look at the code i posted below, that should give you what you need from the 'max' method

Comment: YAY! i removed System.out.println(Numbers); and its ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Change your 'max' method to this. You are comparing each row with the next one. e.g. 5,3,2,4,1 would end up as 4. You need to store the highest one, compare to that, and return the one you end up with.

```
public static int max(int[] array) {
 if(array.length == 0)
     return; //array should have elements

 int maxt = array[0]; 

 for(int i=1;i < array.length;i++)
 {
     if(array[i] >  maxt)
        maxt = array[i];
 }
 return maxt;
}
```

Comment: This should be array.length -1.

Comment: didn't even see that in the code! shouldn't be there at all.

Comment: array.length will give an out of array index bounds